# msmpi.dll error message in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm working on mpi but I keep having this error message :

> (the program can't start because msmpi.dll is missing from your computer try
>        reinstalling the program to fix this problem )

So my question is:

Will uninstalling visual studio and reinstalling it again solve this problem ? or I should go with PC fix kit program and registry fix programs to solve the problem?

What else could be the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem should be solved by reinstalling Microsoft MPI installation, rather than Visual Studio. It helped me in a similar situation.

You can download the latest version from
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb524831(v=vs.85).aspx. msmpisdk.msi installs the SDK (headers and link libraries), msmpisetup.exe installs the runtime support (msmpi.dll,etc).

Comment: This works for ParaView as well!

Comment: In the lastest version as of now there's an msmpi.lib but no msmpi.dll