# In the latest version of MSMPI there's no msmpi.dll

Tags: visual-studio, windows-11, ms-mpi

My Visual Studio 2022 Community is giving me an error when I run my application saying `msmpi.dll` is not found. I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36466513/1227860) and installed the latest version of MSMPI from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100593). `.lib` files are installed but there is no `msmpi.dll`.

Where can I get `msmpi.dll`?

Installation folder of `msmpisdk.msi`

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI> tree  /f
Folder PATH listing for volume Windows
Volume serial number is 5C57-9F08
C:.
├───Include
│   │   mpi.f90
│   │   mpi.h
│   │   mpif.h
│   │   mpio.h
│   │   mspms.h
│   │   pmidbg.h
│   │
│   ├───x64
│   │       mpifptr.h
│   │
│   └───x86
│           mpifptr.h
│
├───Lib
│   ├───x64
│   │       msmpi.lib
│   │       msmpifec.lib
│   │       msmpifmc.lib
│   │
│   └───x86
│           msmpi.lib
│           msmpifec.lib
│           msmpifes.lib
│           msmpifmc.lib
│           msmpifms.lib
│
└───License
        MicrosoftMPI-SDK-EULA.rtf
        MPI-SDK-TPN.txt
```

The installation folder of `msmpisetup.exe`:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI> tree /f
Folder PATH listing for volume Windows
Volume serial number is 5C57-9F08
C:.
├───Benchmarks
│       IMB-MPI1.exe
│       IMB-NBC.exe
│       MpiPingpong.exe
│
├───Bin
│       mpiexec.exe
│       mpitrace.man
│       msmpilaunchsvc.exe
│       smpd.exe
│
├───License
│       MicrosoftMPI-Redistributable-EULA.rtf
│       MPI-Redistributables-TPN.txt
│
└───Redist
        MSMpiSetup.exe
```

Comment: Did you run the installer and choose all the options?  What you have there is just the SDK, which does NOT include the runtime components, including msmpi.dll.

Comment: Yes, neither `msmpisetup.exe` nor `msmpisdk.msi` install `msmpi.dll`.

Comment: Can you please point me to where the installer is?

Comment: The .msi file is the installer.  It should have copied the DLL into the `\Windows\System32` directory.  Did you copy the tree from another computer?